Proof that if $M_t^{\alpha}$ is martingale, then $X_t$ is Brownian motion
Probelm
Let $X_t$ be a continuous process. If $\forall \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ , $M_t^{\alpha}=\exp(\alpha X_t-\alpha^2t/2)$ is a $F_t$ - martingale, can this imply that $X_t$ is a $F_t$ - Brownian motion?
My Approach
Notice that:
$$X_t=\frac{1}{\alpha}\log M_t^\alpha+\frac{\alpha t}{2}$$
By martingale's definition I have: $X_t\in F_t$ .
I want to use Levy’s characterization of brownian motion to proof this. Then I need to verify the following:

$X_0=\frac{1}{\alpha}\log M_0^{\alpha}=0$ , then I only need show that $M_0^\alpha=1,\forall \alpha$ .
$X_t$ is a (local) martingale with respect to $F_t$ ;
$(X_t^2-t)$ is a (local) martingale with respect to $F_t$ ;

by definition I have:
$$\begin{aligned}
E[M_t^{\alpha}|\mathcal{F}_0]&=M_0^{\alpha},\forall \alpha\\
\end{aligned}$$

I have no idea how to derive $M_0^\alpha=1$ from this, simply using martingale's definition seems no help.

& 3. Trying to show that $X_t$ and $X_t^2-t$ are (local) martingales stuck on the verification of $E[X_t|F_s]\ge X_s$ . For $X_t$ , it looks I have to deal with $E[\log M_t^\alpha|F_s]$ and $\log M_s^\alpha$ 's relationship. If $\log M_t^{\alpha}$ is a martingale then I would be happy to deal with it, yet I can't see if it is. Same question remains for $X_t^2-t$ .


Any hint on the problem?

Update
by Snoop's hint, show the mgf of $X_{t_{1}},\cdots,X_{t_{n}}$ where $t_1<\cdots<t_n$ , as below:
$$\begin{aligned}
&E\left[\exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k X_{t_k}\right)\right]\\
&=\exp \left(\frac{t_n \alpha_n^2}{2}\right)E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{\alpha_kX_{t_k}}\cdot e^{\alpha_nX_{t_n}-\frac{t_n \alpha_n^2}{2}}\right]\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{t_n \alpha_n^2}{2}\right)E\left[E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{\alpha_kX_{t_k}}\cdot e^{\alpha_nX_{t_n}-\frac{t_n\alpha_n^2}{2}}\bigg|\mathcal{F}_{t_{n-1}}\right]\right]\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{t_n \alpha_n^2}{2}\right)E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{\alpha_kX_{t_k}}\cdot e^{\alpha_n X_{t_{n-1}}-\frac{t_{n-1}\alpha_n^2}{2}}\right]\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{(t_n-t_{n-1})\alpha_n^2}{2}\right)E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}e^{\alpha_kX_{t_k}}\cdot e^{(\alpha_n+\alpha_{n-1})X_{t_{n-1}}}\right]\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{(t_n-t_{n-1})\alpha_n^2}{2}\right)\cdot \exp\left(\frac{(t_{n-1}-t_{n-2})(\alpha_n+\alpha_{n-1})^2}{2}\right)\\
&\quad \cdot\cdots \cdot\exp\left(\frac{(t_{3}-t_{2})(\alpha_n+\alpha_{n-1}+\cdots+\alpha_3)^2}{2}\right)\\
&\quad \cdot E\left[e^{\alpha_1X_{t_1}}\cdot e^{(\alpha_n+\alpha_{n-1}+\cdots+\alpha_2)X_{t_2}}\right]\\
&=C \cdot e^{\frac{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)^2t_2}{2}}\cdot E\left[E\left[e^{\alpha_1X_{t_1}}\cdot e^{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)X_{t_2}-\frac{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)^2t_2}{2}}\bigg|\mathcal{F}_{t_1}\right]\right]\\
&=C\cdot e^{\frac{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)^2t_2}{2}}\cdot E\left[ e^{\alpha_1X_{t_1}}\cdot e^{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)X_{t_1}-\frac{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)^2t_1}{2}}\bigg|\mathcal{F}_{t_1}\right]\\
&=C\cdot e^{(t_2-t_1)\frac{(\alpha_n+\cdots+\alpha_2)^2}{2}}E\left[ e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)X_{t_1}}\right]\\
&=C'e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)^2t_1/2} E\left[ E\left[e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)X_{t_1}-\frac{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)^2t_1}{2}}\bigg|\mathcal{F}_0\right]\right]\\
&=C'e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)^2t_1/2}E\left[ e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)X_{0}}\right]
\end{aligned}$$
Here:
$$\begin{aligned}
&C'e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)^2t_1/2}\\
&=\exp\left(\frac{\alpha_n^2t_n}{2}+\frac{(2\alpha_n+\alpha_{n-1})\alpha_{n-1}t_{n-1}}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(2\alpha_{n}+\cdots+2\alpha_2+\alpha_1)\alpha_1t_1}{2}\right)\\
&:=e^{\frac{1}{2}\alpha^T\Sigma \alpha}
\end{aligned}$$
The mgf of $X_{t_1},\cdots,X_{t_n}$ can be writen as:
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}\alpha^T\Sigma \alpha}E[e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)X_0}]$$
Where $\Sigma=(t_i\land t_j)_{n\times n}$ .
Conclusion
The condition $X_0=0$ should be imposed. Snoop's answer give an counterexample as below.

I guess $X_0=0$ for simplicity. Note that if $t_1<t_2$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}E[e^{\alpha_1X_{t_1}+\alpha_2X_{t_2}}]&=e^{\frac{t_2\alpha_2^2}{2}}E[e^{\alpha_1X_{t_1}}E[e^{\alpha_2X_{t_2}-\frac{t_2\alpha_2^2}{2}}|\mathscr{F}_{t_1}]]\\
&=e^{\frac{t_2\alpha_2^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{t_1\alpha_2^2}{2}}E[e^{(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)X_{t_1}}]\\
&=e^{\frac{t_2\alpha_2^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{t_1\alpha_2^2}{2}}e^{\frac{t_1(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)^2}{2}}\\
&=e^{\frac{t_2\alpha_2^2}{2}}e^{\frac{t_1(\alpha_1^2+2\alpha_1\alpha_2)}{2}}
\end{aligned}$$
But this is a multivariate Gaussian mgf with mean zero and covariance matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
t_1&t_1\\
t_1&t_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
t_1&t_1\wedge t_2\\
t_1\wedge t_2&t_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This argument can be extended to any collection $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2},...,X_{t_n})$ where $t_1<t_2<...<t_n$. Thus $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ can be shown to be a continuous-path Gaussian process with zero mean and finite-dimensional covariance matrices with entries $(t_k\wedge t_\ell)_{k,\ell}$, which is one of the characterisations of Brownian motion.

I believe the condition $X_0=0$ should be imposed. Indeed, consider $X_t:=W_t+U$ where $W$ is a standard $\mathscr{F}_t$-Brownian motion and $U$ an $\mathscr{F}_0$-measurable Bernoulli random variable which is independent of $W$. Then, for each fixed $\alpha$, $M_t^\alpha$ as defined is a $\mathscr{F}_t$-martingale: it is $(\mathscr{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$-adapted, it is integrable and
$$E[M_t^\alpha (M_s^\alpha)^{-1}|\mathscr{F}_s]=E[e^{\alpha(W_t-W_s)}e^{-(t-s)\alpha^2/2}|\mathscr{F}_s]=1$$
However, $X$ has continuous paths, but it is not a standard Brownian motion.

Thanks! I am now able to write down the mgf of $X_{t_1},\cdots,X_{t_n}$ , yet I got $e^{\frac{1}{2}\alpha^T\Sigma \alpha}E[e^{(\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_n)X_0}]$ (as I updated above). It seems that I have to show $X_0=0$ to turn this mgf into a multivariate gaussian mgf.

You are welcome @Ning (please do leave an upvote if this helped!). For the condition $X_0=0$, let me think about it.

@Ning I have added an argument about $X_0$. Please let me know if this makes sense to you.

Yes, I think your argument is right. The revised answer also excludes other "nonstandard" Brownian motions (i.e. scaling or translation) by adjusting $W_t$ to the corresponding form.

BM is characterized as a continuous process with  increments  $X_t - X_s \sim N(0,t-s),~t>s$, independent of ${\cal F}_s$.
We have
\begin{align*}  
E[ e^{\alpha (X_t - X_s)} |{\cal F}_s ] &= E[ e^{\alpha X_t} |{\cal F}_s] e^{-\alpha X_s}\\
&  = E[ M^\alpha_t e^{\alpha^2 t/2} |{\cal F}_s] e^{-\alpha X_s} \\
& = M^{\alpha}_s e^{\alpha^2 t/2}  e^{-\alpha X_s}\\
& = e^{\alpha^2 (t-s)/2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore:

By taking expectations,  the distribution of $X_t-X_s\sim N(0,t-s)$.
Because the conditional distribution is equal to the expectation, $X_t-X_s$ is independent of ${\cal F}_s$.

As noted, this does not mean the process is standard BM, as the initial distribution is yet to be determined.

Hi Fnacool. By BM's defination, shouldn't we indicate that $X_t-X_s$ is independent $\mathcal{F}_r(0\leq r\leq s)$ ? Then to show this, according to your answer, we consider proof $e^{\alpha(X_t-X_s)}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_r}(0\leq r\leq s)$ , I think we should write:
$$E[e^{\alpha(X_t-X_s)}\big|\mathcal{F}_r]=e^{\frac{\alpha^2(t-s)}{2}},\forall 0\leq r\leq s\leq t$$
here, right?

$$\begin{aligned}
E[e^{\alpha(X_t-X_s)}|\mathcal{F}_r]&=E\left[E\left[e^{\alpha(X_t-X_s)}\big|\mathcal{F}_s\right]\big| \mathcal{F}_r\right]\
&=e^{\frac{\alpha^2t}{2}}E[e^{-\alpha X_s}E[M_t^\alpha|\mathcal{F}_s]|\mathcal{F}_r]\
&=e^{\frac{\alpha^2t}{2}}E[e^{-\alpha X_s}M_s^\alpha|\mathcal{F}_r]\
&=e^{\frac{\alpha^2t}{2}}E[e^{-\frac{\alpha^2s}{2}}|\mathcal{F}_r]\
&=e^{\frac{\alpha^2(t-s)}{2}}
\end{aligned}$$

No need. ${\cal F}_s\supseteq {\cal F}_r$, so if $X_t-X_s$ is independent of ${\cal F}_s$, it is independent of ${\cal F}_r$...
